# D3 - Loading data from JSON doesn't work

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

I'm starting to learn D3 and it seems like a powerful framework. I'm trying load the following html from simple python webserver. I can see that the .json file is loaded, but I don't see that json getting printed in the console log of chrome browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>D3 Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/d3.v3/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset;
    console.log("Before json");
    d3.json("pie-chart-data.json",function(error,data){
        if (error) return console.warn(error);
        dataset = data;
        console.log("Dataset is: "+dataset);
    });
    console.log("After json");
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JSON file- pie-chart-data.json

```
[
{key: "One",y: 5},
{key: "Two",y: 2},
{key: "Three",y: 9},
{key: "Four",y: 7},
{key: "Five",y: 4},
{key: "Six",y: 3},
{key: "Seven",y: .5}
]
```

I see the "Before json" and "After json" getting printed to the console, but don't see the "Dataset is" log. Where am I going wrong - please help.

Thanks, K.

Comment: Can you access the json file using the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can access it using the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The json file is malformed, it must have double quotes around the keys, and the numbers must begin with a digit or with a minus sign (not with a point).

```
[
    {"key": "One",   "y": 5},
    {"key": "Two",   "y": 2},
    {"key": "Three", "y": 9},
    {"key": "Four",  "y": 7},
    {"key": "Five",  "y": 4},
    {"key": "Six",   "y": 3},
    {"key": "Seven", "y": 0.5}
]
```

The complete json specification and syntax can be found in [json.org](http://www.json.org/).